# Proper use of isinstance in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a class with a method that loads data into an attached pandas dataframe. I want my method to be polymorphic, so I have a couple of `isinstance` checks on the data.

I have read before that in python checking data types can be bad practice, but in this case I believe it is relevant. Is this a good practice of coding in this case, or is there a better way to think about this?

```
def add_data(self, data, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(data, six.string_types):
        if data.lower().endswith('.csv'):
            self.csv_toFrame(data, kwargs)
        elif data.lower().endswith('.xls', '.xlsx'):
            self.excel_toFrame(data, kwargs)

    elif isinstance(data, pd.DataFrame):
        self.data_df = data

    elif isinstance(data, Variable):
        self.data_df = data.var_df

    return
```

Comment: Not that this is necessarily strong evidence, but within the `DataFrame.__init__` source itself there are multiple `isinstance` checks to handle all the different kinds of arguments it can receive.

Comment: At the end of the if/elif/elif statement it would be good to have something like - else: raise ValueError('unexpected data type').  Just so that it does not fail silently if the wrong kind of data is passed in.

Comment: I am definitely going to add some kind of else clause, but probably just a warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong in principle with using isinstance, there are some times when it is the only solution. I think that you have a good example of a case where it's the better option.

In Python, we generally prefer "duck typing." Rather than checking if an object is an instance of a particular class, we just check to see if it has the methods we need. In your specific case, there doesn't seem to be much of a difference between using isinstance and duck typing.

A duck typed version of your code might look like:

```
def add_data(self, data, **kwargs):
     try:  
          self.csv_toFrame(data, kwargs)
     except:
            try:
                self.excel_toFrame(data, kwargs)
            except:
                try:
                     self.data_df = data.var_df
                except:             
                     #some check to make sure it's a data-frame
                     self.data_df = data

      return
```

Which I would argue is much less readable than your original code.

On the other hand, it might be worth thinking about if you want your data to be a filestream, and modify csv_toFrame and excel_toFrame to accept streams. You would have to adjust your type checks